# How to force panel not to be on top?

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, gnome-panel

I am trying to present a full screen slideshow using OOo Impress, but the top panel stays on top of the slideshow. I went to `Slideshow->Slideshow Settings...` and made sure `Always on top` was checked.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the window `Right Click > Always On Top`?

Comment: @Marco: Yup. Didn't work either.

Comment: Does it vary depending on whether you use Metacity or Compiz?

Comment: Hmmm... I've only tried it out with Compiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a bug in Ubuntu and there is no fix available yet.

The bug is tracked [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openoffice.org/+bug/525807) but unfortunately most of the workarounds didn't work for me. Feel free to try them on your system:

> As funnylife_ma mentioned, you could
>   either disable compiz (not ideal) or
>   you could just disable the Place
>   Windows plugin. Simply trying to
>   untick Place Windows didn't work as
>   after a few seconds it would be
>   re-enabled (I assume another plugin
>   required it). To do this I had to go
>   into CCSM > Preferences > Plugin List,
>   un-tick Automatic Plugin Sorting (and
>   acknowledge the warning saying I know
>   what I'm doing) then disable Place.
>   Not ideal but a lot better than
>   auto-hide panels or no compiz.

--or--

> Go to System - Preferences - Conmpiz
>   Config Settings Manager
>
> In this screen click on utilities on
>   the left, click on workarounds on the
>   right. Put a checkmark for the enable
>   legacy full screen support

--or--

Install OOo from openoffice.org like [this](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=68)

The workaround that works is to disable Compiz by setting Visual Efects to None in System → Preferences → Appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set **Visual Effects** to **None** in **Appearance Preferences**.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

1. `F11` that puppy before you full screen. I hopefully that will help with the panel.
2. If not I believe [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1313657) has a possible solution to your problem.

Keep me posted, let me know if they works with you.